# Am I using the find method of the folder class correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script

I had a script that used the find method of the folder class and it has worked fine for quite a while. Suddenly today it stopped working. I get the 'We're sorry, a server error occured. Please wait a bit and try again' message. It stopped working this morning.

I was able to recreate this error with just a few lines of code in new small script.

```
function myFunction() {
 folder = DocsList.getFolder('test');
 folder.find('testfile');
 Logger.log('anything');
}
```

I made sure I had a folder called test and a file called testfile inside of it.

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Confirmed. I tested this code, using a folder that exists, and a file that exists. I got the same message. Smells like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been recently reported as an issue -

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2482

Please star it so that you can get notified of updates.

Comment: Thank you for finding that. When I searched for the issue on Google Code I was looking for something related to the folder class. I guess it makes sense that this is really a DocsList issue.